# How to get list of apps assigned to me using the Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible using the Microsoft Graph to retrieve the list of applications assigned to me (basically the information displayed at myapps.microsoft.com)?

Comment: This is may help (but not exactly what you need): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Right, so this shows all applications in the AAD rather than applications assigned to me. Still a bit helpful, thank you 